# Reading xls file returns error "VirtualAlloc of 4710203392 bytes failed with errno=1455"

Tags: go

Reading xls file in Go with package `github.com/extrame/xls` but it returns a memory error like `VirtualAlloc of 4710203392 bytes failed with errno=1455`

```
file, _ := xls.Open("test.xls", "utf-8")
```

How can I increase memory or any other package I can use in Go?

Comment: xls.Open()' return error is nil??

Comment: xls.Open() is working fine with less entries in file but if i upload a file with more no of entries it throw error

Comment: what size file causes a 4.7GB allocation to happen?

Comment: my file size is 8753 KB

Comment: Go doesn't _throw_ errors (or anything else). It returns errors.

Comment: I suspect that the file is either too large to fit into memory (you ruled that out in your comment), or corrupt, or that it triggers a bug in the `xls` package which makes the package think that the file has this size?

Comment: @Flimzy - it may occasionaly panic though, which to the uninitiated looks suspiciously similar to throwing ;)